# A browser starts to download a file instead of page rendering

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, spring-websocket

Since we deployed our application with a WebSocket feature we noticed a following problem:

Once a 5-10 page reloads instead of a new page a browser starts to download a short (2 bytes) file. The problem seems to be random.

The problem doesn't appear on a "bare" Tomcat deployment.

Our stack is:

- OS: CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
- Tomcat
- Apache: 2.4.6
- proxy_wstunnel 2.4.6
- Java: java version "1.7.0_72"
- Grails 2.4.4
- spring-websocket:1.2.0

httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.application.com
    Redirect / https://my.application.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{request_uri} [R=301,L]
    ServerAdmin webmaster@datacave.ch
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile my.application.com.key
    SSLCertificateFile my.application.com.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile sub.class4.server.ca.pem
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    ServerName my.application.com
    ServerAlias application1.application.local
    ErrorLog /var/www/logs/application/application-error_log
    CustomLog /var/www/logs/application/application-access_log combined
    <FilesMatch "\.(eot|woff|ttf|otf|svg)">
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(.+\.)?(application.com|application.local)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0$1
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
        </IfModule>
    </FilesMatch>
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    SSLProxyEngine          Off
    ProxyRequests           Off
    ProxyPass               /       ajp://application1.application.local:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse        /       ajp://application1.application.local:8009/
</VirtualHost>
```

server.xml

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNioProtocol" redirectPort="8080" URIEncoding='UTF-8'/>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: have you set the `content-type` in the response headers properly?

Comment: I believe that headers are properly added by Grails/Spring itself. Moreover the problem appears only for Tomcat-Apache combination. It works fine on bare Tomcat.